# Magento 1.9: Get last row in getModel

Tags: magento-1.9, database, getmodel

So, most of the time I saw using `getFirstItem` and `getLastItem` used in case of collection.

But I  can't see any possible method to get the last item for `::getModel())`

So, is there a possible way to get the last item when not using collection but instead just using `getModel("..")->load();`

```
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 102
        [payment_tbl_id] => 924
        [order_id] => 3151
        [pg] => razorpay
        [amount] => 160.00
        [status] => 1
        [refund_transaction_id] => 
        [stop_refund] => 
        [stop_refund_reason] => 
        [created_at] => 2020-04-17 07:49:53
        [updated_at] => 2020-04-17 07:49:53
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 103
        [payment_tbl_id] => 924
        [order_id] => 3151
        [pg] => razorpay
        [amount] => 15.00
        [status] => 1
        [refund_transaction_id] => 
        [stop_refund] => 
        [stop_refund_reason] => 
        [created_at] => 2020-04-17 07:50:23
        [updated_at] => 2020-04-17 07:50:23
    )
```

)

This is the output of `getResourceModel`, as it can be seen there can be mutilple rows, but I need to fetch the last one and make the stop_refund value as 1, and update the row  in db.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
$itemCollection = $this->getResourceModel('my_moudle/model') //loads collection
    //->addFieldToFilter('field', 'value') //add field to filter if you need to so that your collection is smaller
    ;

if ($itemCollection->getSize()) {
   $item = $itemCollection->getLastItem(); //gets the last item

   //now update $item
   $item->setStopRefund('my_value')->save();
}
```